# Git Clone issue

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I'm trying to clone some code I have in a private repository using the following command:

```
git clone https://github.com/username/repo_name.git
```

When I do this I get the error in the following format:

> fatal: https://github.com/username/repo_name.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found: did you run it update-server-info on the server?

How do I fix this issue?  Am I using the the wrong URL when I'm trying to clone the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As illustrated in [this issue](https://github.com/boxen/boxen/issues/49), this is generally linked to an incorrect address:

- incorrect username (or correct one, but with a wrong case)
- incorrect reponame (or correct one, but with a wrong case)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I think you should use `git clone git@github.com:username/repo_name.git`.

By the way, I can see you added `github-for-windows` tag - the easiest way to clone repo is to open GitHub for Windows application and  clone it from there, because that way you can also clone any submodules you have in the repo without adding any parameters to `git clone` command.

Comment: When I type that in from the command line, I get the following error:  ERROR: Repository not found

Comment: Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.